# How to resolve this stack install issue?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm working on some of the [`exercism.io`](http://exercism.io/languages/haskell/tests) Haskell problems. Unfortunately, `stack test` fails when it tries to install `hspec`.

I don't really know how else to debug this. I'd appreciate any help.

Output:

```
$ stack install hspec
quickcheck-io-0.1.3: configure
quickcheck-io-0.1.3: build
hspec-expectations-0.7.2: configure
hspec-expectations-0.7.2: build
Progress: 2/4
--  While building package hspec-expectations-0.7.2 using:
      /Users/me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/me/projects/excercism.io/haskell/space-age/.stack-work/logs/hspec-expectations-0.7.2.log

    Configuring hspec-expectations-0.7.2...
    Building hspec-expectations-0.7.2...
    Preprocessing library hspec-expectations-0.7.2...
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HUnit-1.3.1.1-21JuQs5D85SLjuJsLVrBpA
        (use -v for more information)


--  While building package quickcheck-io-0.1.3 using:
      /Users/me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/me/projects/excercism.io/haskell/space-age/.stack-work/logs/quickcheck-io-0.1.3.log

    Configuring quickcheck-io-0.1.3...
    Building quickcheck-io-0.1.3...
    Preprocessing library quickcheck-io-0.1.3...
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HUnit-1.3.1.1-21JuQs5D85SLjuJsLVrBpA
        (use -v for more information)
```

All the log files look basically the same. The don't change when I run `stack install -v hspec`.

```
    # /Users/me/projects/excercism.io/haskell/space-age/.stack-work/logs/hspec-expectations-0.7.2.log
    Building hspec-expectations-0.7.2...
    Preprocessing library hspec-expectations-0.7.2...
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HUnit-1.3.1.1-21JuQs5D85SLjuJsLVrBpA
        (use -v for more information)
me:space-age λ less /Users/me/projects/excercism.io/haskell/space-age/.stack-work/logs/hspec-expectations-0.7.2.log
```

Debugging information:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.2.0 x86_64 hpack-0.14.0

$ type -a stack
stack is /Users/me/.local/bin/stack
```

Comment: `stack install hspec` works for me, with the same version of stack, cabal, and ghc. Are you using a special stack.yaml file?

Comment: How did you install Stack and GHC?

Comment: I downloaded stack a while ago -- don't really remember. But I updated with `stack upgrade`. ghc was installed originally through haskell platform, which might be causing some conflicts? How can I debug that?

Comment: To test if it's due to the globally installed ghc, you can add `system-ghc: false` to your `~/.stack/config.yaml`.  Then, use `stack setup` to install a stack-managed ghc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the globally installed `ghc`.

I was able to solve the problem by removing `/Library/Haskell` directory and Haskell symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/`.